# Cloudera Installation Error I want to know can we cloudera manager for Hadoop single node Cluster on ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, amazon-cloudfront, cloudera, hadoop-streaming

I am using ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I installed and ran sample hadoop programs with single node successfully.

I am getting the following error while installing cloudera manager on my ubuntu

> Refreshing repository metadata failed. See
>   /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/2.refresh-repo.log for details.
>   Click OK to revert this installation.

I want to know can we install Cloudera for Hadoop's Single node cluster on ubuntu. Please response me that Is it possible to install cloudera  manager for single node or not. Or else Am i want to create multiple nodes for using cloudera with my hadooop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CM can run in a single node.

This error is because CM can not use apt-get install to get the packages. Which tutorial do you follow?

However, you can manually add the cloudera repo. See this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/scm-users/dN_mu5Wmlxo).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the : http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html

Comment: After I tire I am getting this Error What changes i have to do for that.--->Cloudera Manager Server failed to start. See /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/7.start-scm-server.log for 
details. Click OK to revert this installation.

Comment: Can you paste /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/7.start-scm-server.log here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @zsxwing. I installed Cloudera for localhost. I'm new to the Hadoop and cloudera. But I have a doubt, I want to configure 1 master with 3 slaves with cloudera. I want to know, Am I want to install hadoop & cloudera in all the three slaves and in master?.